# Are `join` and `fmap join` equals in Haskell (from Category theory point of view)?

Tags: haskell, types, monads, category-theory

My question arises from first law of monads in Haskell: `join . fmap join = join . join`.

In [Haskell/Category_theory](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory#Monads) this law is demonstrated by the following picture:

[image]

I am confused by the fact that this example uses instances of types, not the types. Because the objects in category `Hask` are types, not their instances.

So I tried to redraw this example with types, and here what I got:
[image]

In this picture both arrows (`join` and `fmap join`) leads to the `M(M(X))`. Is this the same object, or there are two different `M(M(X))`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am confused by the fact that this example uses instances of types, not the types. Because the objects in category Hask are types, not their instances.

The example uses an instance of a *class*, which is itself a *type*.

---

In Haskell, yes this is the same object (type). Instances of the `Monad` typeclass have to be type constructors and type constructors are injective. Then, it should be pretty clear that

```
X = X   =>   M(X) = M(X)   =>   M(M(X)) = M(M(X))
```

The catch here is that that only means they are the same type, not value. Just because `fmap join` and `join` can both have their types specialized to `Monad m => m (m (m a)) -> m (m a)` does not mean that they do the same thing.

They don't.

```
ghci> (fmap join) [[[1],[2],[3]]]
[[1,2,3]]         
ghci> join [[[1],[2],[3]]]
[[1],[2],[3]]
```

Not all drawings of categories have to end up being commuting diagrams. :)

Comment: I see (just a comment), the resulting structure in the same but the value is not. Which is the point of monads, compared to monad transformers: to affect the `a` in `m a` but leave the `m`; compared to monad transformers which would affect the `m` and leave the `a`.

Answer (score 7):

From the picture, you can see that `fmap join` and `join` produce *different* values of the same *type*. Thus, they are not the same, even though their *composition* with `join` ultimately produces identical values.

In category theory, an [*epimorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism) is a morphism `g` such that `f1 . g == f2 . g` implies that `f1 == f2` as well. In this case, we can see that `join` is *not* an epimorphism, because although `fmap join . join == join. join`, it is not true that `fmap join == join`.